# What are semantic actions?

Tags: javascript, jquery

I read the "jQuery in Action" book. The following statement is unclear for me:

> The triggerHandler method invokes handlers without bubbling, semantic actions, or live events.

What are semantic actions?

Comment: there's an article on github by Phillipe Sigaud https://github.com/PhilippeSigaud/Pegged/wiki/Semantic-Actions , and a rather handy pdf at https://engineering.purdue.edu/~milind/ece468/2014fall/lecture-04.pdf. Also check out http://youmightnotneedjquery.com/

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Semantic actions (usually referred as the default actions) are built-in predefined event handlers, which are defined by HTML itself. To prevent execution of such actions you need to perform special means.

Examples of such actions:

- clicking an anchor tag - page reloading
- clicking a submit button - form submission
- pressing a mouse button over a text and moving it – text selection
- clicking a checkbox - check box state change